# Azure Powershell cannot login

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to log into Azure from PowerShell using the command

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

And it opens a popup window where I enter my email, then click personal account and then I get the error

> "Because you're accessing sensitive info, you need to verify your password."

But then there is no action to perform.  There's no button to click or anything. I'm logged into Azure in both Chrome and Edge.  What is going on here? This seems like a bug with the Azure website. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Try logging in IE, I had this problem in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do your receive some code or link on your phone or on an another email? If you can login to http://portal.azure.com from Edge or Chrome, I recommend to open a support ticket (you will find "Help + Support" in the services list).

Comment: Did you try closing your browsers and clearing cookies?

Comment: Could you please upload the screenshot of this issue? It helps us to have better understanding of your situation. Normally, this command will pops up a window to let you input the account and password.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys!  I can't reproduce this issue anymore, so I'm not going to post a screenshot. Basically just the password textbox and the submit button wouldn't render for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think something was broken with their site. I was also using a third party console, cmder. When I used the built-in PowerShell console, I was able to login.  Also, I can no longer reproduce the issue, so it seems like they fixed the issue.